# How do I specfy an int32_t output parameter with a scanf format on a 64-bit processor?

Tags: c, scanf

If int is 64 bits, can I assume, that %d produces int?
What is then %hd, %ld, %lld and what if I want int32_t as output?

Answer (score 1):

In the "inttypes.h" header are a number of macros for format specifiers to be used for fixed width types, regardless of environment

For a `int32_t` printed in decimal format, you would use the `PRId32` macro.  For example:

```
int32_t x;
printf("x = %" PRId32 "\n", x);
```

This macro expands to a string containing the `d` format specifier and any necessary size modifiers.  The above code also takes advantage of the compiler merging strings that appear one after the other.